# Multiple rewrite rules in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have an .htaccess file that rewrites urls for SEO purposes

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /display.php?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^search/([^/\.]+)/?$ search.php?what=$1&where=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Now the first rewrite rule works fine. (www.domain.com/user goes to display.php?page=user)
but the second one should work like (www.domain.com/search/something/else must go to search.php?what=something&where=else

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Your second rule is incorrect for what you are looking for. You are requesting the result of two captures, but are only making one capture.

Try this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^search/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ search.php?what=$1&where=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Edit: You'll also need to switch your rules around. Your first rule captures everything, and would therefore discard the second.

So, swap them around, and use the `L` flag, as suggested already.

Comment: Doesn't work either, I see what you mean though. But I'm not getting the first capture even if I remove the second one.

Comment: What output do you get? (Also, you'll need to switch your rules around. So, `search` should be first.)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `[L]` flag, which [causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l).

Try removing the `L` flag from the first Rewrite Rule, like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /display.php?page=$1 [NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^search/([^/\.]+)/?$ search.php?what=$1&where=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Aren't you missing a `/` in front of `search.php`?  Shouldn't it be `/search.php?what=$1&where=$2`

Comment: Nope, no changes. It does look like it should be there though